# In gimp: How do I create a new file / open an xcf file?

Tags: snow-leopard, image-editing

I downloaded "gimp 2.8.10 for Snow Leopard & Lion & Mountain Lion" from gimp.lisanet as indicated by gimp.org and installed it on an intel mac 64 bits under 10.6.8. The installation seems to have worked BUT:

1. File > New opens a window "Create a New Image" but, after picking a template from the given choices, when I click OK nothing more happens.
2. When I open an xcf file (created in Seashore) with a 72 dpi resolution, gimp gives the warning resolution out of range in XCF file. After I click OK, nothing more happens.
3. When I double-click an xcf file (created in Seashore) with a 72 dpi resolution, gimp is launched and nothing more happens.

Please note that I am a gimp newbee so that I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: The LisaNet version has some added features, but since it had been altered it may or may not have an error inside. You could try to reinstall GIMP from that source or try the unaltered native version [here](http://download.gimp.org/pub/gimp/v2.8/osx/gimp-2.8.14.dmg).

Comment: I just downloaded 2.8.14 from "here" as well as from gimp.org. Both behave as above. When trying to open a jepg, it asks about RGB and then nothing more.

Comment: The version from "here" was the unaltered version from their site [gimp.org](http://www.gimp.org/downloads) (the "this link" above the LisaNet version). If both behave the same, I believe that something else outside the installer package is causing your error then. Have you tried to do the same in a [new user account](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH11468)? If it is working there, your original user account may need a closer look or simply move your data to the new user account and move on. If the new user account behaves the same, Mac OS X needs to be troubleshooted.

Comment: Fact is that I downloaded the gimp.org version just a few hours ago myself with Mac OS X 10.10.4 and it works there without issue. So, speaking generally, I know that the application as such works.

Comment: I opened a new account, downloaded several versions. None of them would open New. I also used Onyx to check and repair. Still the same. It seems, though, that Gimp leaves things lying around because Onyx asked "Where is gimp-bin" after I had cleared everything. Sigh.

Comment: When you install GIMP, it will on its initial launch create some hidden files in the user directory. However, since it does not work in another account as well, I guess that something supporting applications like GIMP from the OS is not working as it should. What you can try is to install the latest combo update onto your installation of Mac OS X. This will replace all updated system files with fresh ones from the combo update. Alternatively, you can use the Snow Leopard disc to do a so called Archive & Install, installing it over the existing installation and then apply the combo update.

Comment: As a last resort, you could freshly install Mac OS X onto your computer. However, if you go that route, think of using Time Machine to make a last backup before committing this step. Otherwise, you will lose all your personal files. You can restore them later after having installed Mac OS X and all updates again.